# To Jeff Haynie: Why do appcelerator pack a JS compiler?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, titanium, appcelerator

I read lots of articles on how Titanium works and I still don't understand why you need to ship a javascript engine with the code?

The answer I found everywhere is "We need it for dynamic code", what does that mean exactly? Like... click events? Then I don't understand why you can't kind of parse the code that is in every events and  kind of make it Objective-C or Java code.

I'm just wondering because that JS engine sometimes takes a lot of resources (i.e. when you create a window with lots of elements and that you open it once returned from app.ui.createCoolView(); it takes like .5 sec to open)

Answer (score 1):

Titanium used the JS compiler, because it actually isn't generating native code at all. Your code will be put on the device not matter what.

Instead, your code will call the Titanium code, to execute a native functionality.
Therefore, every API call you do to the Titanium API, will be executed natively.

If you do JavaScript stuff which doesn't use any API calls, it will be executed as JavaScript. But, you won't see anything as a result of that of course.